# Is there a prebuilt version of python 2.7 mySql db APIs to install and use with django or do i have to really build it from scratch?

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows-xp, installation

i want to install django and use mysql as the backend.

i installed django and it worked fine.  i am now following the first tutorial and created mysite.

After putting the mysql backend into into the settings.py, the web server no longer ran.  I get the following error:

**raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb**

i already have a mysql instance setup on a remote machine.  i changed the settings.py file with my db info but following to install and the initial tutorial, it still seems to want me to install Python database API 2.0 interface for the MySQL 5.1 database.

the only links i see are to the source code.

Is there a prebuilt version of mysql for python libraries that work for python 2.7 and are built so i don't need C++ compilers, etc on my machine to get django setup.

Comment: What exactly want you to install the mysql server? Can you give the commands you entered + the output?

Comment: This should be possible. What's your OS?

Comment: @Rudi - i was just following this tutorial . . half way down the page you see the db setup section: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: @Thomas @Rudi - i updated the question with the error messages

Comment: Did you install mysql-python?  http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Comment: @ooo:  The answer is "No".  Since that's useless, your question needs to be improved.  Please **update** the title to say what you need to know.  Please change the title so it isn't a complaint.

Comment: @S.Lott - let me know if the updated question title and description works for you . .

Comment: You certainly do not need a `Python enabled` MySQL server (because MySQL just listens for requests on a given port and does not care what language the application that issues them is written in). Whatever you need is related to your Python instalation, not to MySQL.

Comment: @Mchl - am referring to: Python database API 2.0 interface for the MySQL 5.1 database

Comment: Oh ok. Somehow I understood you're looking for some special version of MySQL. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows you might try the binary installer from http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

On linux you would normally install it using the native package manager, e.g. `sudo apt-get install mysql-python` or via `sudo easy_install mysqld`.

The `easy_install` way will also work on windows provided you have installed the right version of Visual Studio (2010?) or mingw.